# Calculate size of json object from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, response

I need to calculate size of json object returned from ajax response.

[image: response image]

I am trying to calculate size using JSON_VALUE.length and getting value 43204.
i am not sure if this is right.
i want exactly same value shown in image.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean `(JSON_VALUE.length/1024).toFixed(1)+"KB"` - paste it into an editor and select all to see how big it is

Answer (score 0):

Convert `JSON_VALUE` to `string_value` and then do the following:

```
var string_value = JSON.stringify(JSON_VALUE);
var JSON_VALUE_in_KB = string_value.length / 1024;
```